# PHP Get new instance of class from array (submitted via POST)

Tags: php

Is there a method to get a new instance from a given class when an array is provided? Something like `function foo($array, $class){return "new instance of class with prefilled member variables"}`?

With PDO you can use the constant PDO::FETCH_CLASS in PDOStatement::fetch to get a new instance of the provided class filled with the fetched data.

I want to use it for this:

1. An user submitted a HTML form (for example, with fields `firstname` and `lastname` and a hidden field with value "Person").
2. I get the form data with $_POST (with appropiate filtering/sanitizing).
3. I want to "convert" that data to an instance of the correct class (in this example `Person`).

Is there a method to do this or do I need to write my own (for all of my classes)?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I'm a programmer, so of course I would want the easiest way :P I have a lot of classes and I hoped that there was already a generic method for this, because PDO has it (so it exists somewhere). So rather than reinvent the wheel, I wanted to know if someone already has done that.

Comment: Not "for all of my classes", just write a function that uses introspection and tries to match every property name from the given class to every field from the post data, and if everything matches, then do the assignment and return the instance.

Comment: This is highly subjective, but would suggest looking into `MVC` and `REST` API. Your `controller(s)` would handle the `$_POST` request and you would program the creation of the appropriate `model(s)` (object) and `view` (response), while REST would allow you to translate routes to call specific controller methods. A good reference for your specific use-case would be to look at how `composer.phar` creates its optimized `autoloader` or something more advanced like a PHP Framework (Symfony, CodeIgniter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something quite simple like this. Create a base class that you can extend if you want a class to be loadable from $_POST.

Then its a simple foreach to load only what exists in the class from the $_POST or $_GET array

```
class Base {

    public function load_post($post) 
    {
        foreach ($post as $field=>$val){
            if ( property_exists($this, $field)){
                $this->{$field} = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person extends Base 
{
    public $one;
    public $two;
    public $three;

    public function __construct($vars)
    {
        if ( isset($vars) ){
            parent::load_post($vars);

        }
    }
}

// pseodo $_POST array
$form_vars = ['one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3];

$p = new Person($form_vars);
print_r($p);
```

Result

```
Person Object
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
)
```

You could also write this extra function as a TRAIT

```
trait load_post {

    public function load_post($post) 
    {
        foreach ($post as $field=>$val){
            if ( property_exists($this, $field)){
                $this->{$field} = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person 
{
    use load_post;

    public $one;
    public $two;
    public $three;

    public function __construct($vars)
    {
        if ( isset($vars) ){
            $this->load_post($vars);

        }
    }
}

// pseodo $_POST array
$form_vars = ['one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3];

$p = new Person($form_vars);
print_r($p);
```

Comment: Something like this was what I had in mind if there was no such method. Thank you for the code, it's really simple. The only down part is that every class must extend the Base class (doesn't look really good and I like to write clean code if possible). I'll wait with accepting this as an answer till this evening so others can react.

Comment: Do you prefer to use TRAIT's

Comment: Personally I almost always start with a empty BASE class, as almost always something happens half way through a project that make it really useful to me when the inevitable scope creep bites

Comment: I didn't know about TRAIT's, thank you. I got a quick look at it, it looks a bit strange. I will study it a bit more this week. I am a Java developer and I know a little bit of PHP (the rough basics). I think mostly in Java, so PHP is a bit different.

Comment: Thank you for the update with a TRAIT example, this looks nicer than extending the base class.